# Error integrating TestCafe with Azure Devops

Tags: azure, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am following this tutorial on integrating TestCafe with Azure Devops https://testcafe.io/documentation/402822/guides/continuous-integration/azure-devops.
I run the script `npm run test testcafe` which locally runs testcafe.  I also tried `npm run test` and get a similar error

This is what I am getting as a result
[image]

I have done some searches for this and have been unable to find what is going on.
Anyone have experience with this?

Comment: If you use the same npm commands locally, does it run the tests? Do you install node and all project dependencies before starting testcafe?

Answer (score 1):

Your Node.js version is outdated. [The minimal supported version for TestCafe is v12.0.0](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/blob/master/package.json#L19). Use the Node.js v12.0.0+ CI environment and make sure that you are using the latest TestCafe version.